# How can I compare by this two algorithms?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o-notation

I have two algorithms has a complexity of O (n log n) and the B-complex algorithm (n^2). By imposing NA size the larger issue that a algorithm can solve in a given time and NB size the larger issue that the B algorithm can solve in the same time on the same machine. Prove that NB < NA.

How can I solve this question ? 
Thank you

Comment: Please credit the original source of the problem.

Comment: The statement you've been asked to prove isn't true in the generality that it's been stated. Suppose that $B$ takes exactly $n^2$ steps and $A$ takes $10^{10}n\log n$ steps. Then, for example, for all inputs of length less than $10^{10}$, $B$ is faster.

Comment: Actually, it's an exercise from my teacher, but I didn't know how to solve it. 
Thank you so much @DavidRicherby